# How to unstage all files since branching

Tags: git

Lets say I branch off master and make a branch called `xo-wip`, make 30 commits and stage all the files/changes. Now I want to unstage every single edit I did in the `xo-wip` branch but not get rid of it. How would I do that?

Currently I have to make a new branch off master say `xo-wip-release`, and then `git merge --squash xo-wip` into `xo-wip-release`

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. git reset <filename> to unstage files that have not been committed. If they've been committed then you have to do something like rollback the branch to an older commit.

Comment: I want to unstage files that have been committed but only since my branch off master. I also dont want to rollback to an older commit because I will lose changes

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

To stage a file, use `git add`.  To unstage a file, use `git reset`.  None of this will help until you properly understand Git's *index*, though.

#### Long

This question does not seem to make sense, which makes me believe you probably have the wrong idea of what Git's index is.  The index, which is also called the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*, is a somewhat hidden data structure that is quite crucial to using Git, but is poorly explained by much Git documentation and even some Git books.

#### Git commits and Git's work-tree

You are probably already familiar with commits and Git's idea of the *work-tree*, but let's go over them again briefly.  A *commit*, in Git, contains a complete snapshot of the entire source code (or whatever it is that you are versioning).  Each commit is uniquely identified by its *hash ID*, which is a big ugly thing: `git log` prints commit IDs and when you run `git log` you may see, e.g.:

```
commit c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231
Author: Junio C Hamano ...
```

Besides saving a source snapshot, each commit also saves the hash ID of a previous or *parent* commit.  Git uses these to chain commits together, in a backwards fashion, starting with the *last* commit and working backwards.  A *branch name* like `master` or `xo-wip` simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit that is in that branch.  If we use uppercase letters to stand in for big ugly hash IDs, we can draw this situation:

```
          I   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J--K--L   <-- xo-wip
```

Here the name `master` identifies commit `I`, and the name `xo-wip` identifies commit `L`.  From `L`, Git works backwards to `K` and then `J` and then `H`.  From `I`, Git works backwards to `H`.  (So which branch is commit `H`, or anything before `H` like `G`, on?  In Git, these are on *both branches at the same time*.  This is one of several things that makes Git downright peculiar, compared to most other version control systems.)

Since every commit holds a complete snapshot of every file, you might wonder how Git can avoid using up all your disk space.  The answer is that files stored *in* commits are stored in a special, compressed, Git-only format.  Moreover, once stored in Git, each version of a file is frozen—read-only, saved for all time—so every commit that shares the *same* version of the file can just *re-use* the compressed, Git-only, frozen file.

The *work-tree* is simply where Git expands out these files into their normal everyday form.  This lets you work on them, hence the name "work-tree" or "working tree".  A `git checkout` selects a commit—you say *which* commit you want, and Git extracts that commit, into your work-tree.  That commit is then your *current commit*.  The current commit has a special name `@` or `HEAD`.  Normally, Git attaches the word `HEAD` to a branch name, and then `@` is the commit to which the branch name points:

```
          I   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J--K--L   <-- xo-wip (HEAD)
```

The current commit—`HEAD` or `@`—is now commit `L`.

You can also put, in your work-tree, files that *aren't* stored into Git.  These files are *untracked*, and if a file is untracked, Git will generally complain about it, so you can mark particular untracked files as also being *ignored*.  (You cannot ignore a tracked file, only an untracked file.)

#### The index, aka the staging area

The word-picture above (and the literal picture of commits) do not include anything called an index or staging area.  That's because Git's index is, by and large at least, *invisible*—it's not something you can view directly.<sup>1</sup>  In fact, once you know what the index is, you might wonder why Git has one at all.  Other version control systems get away without one.  Git has it, though, and—if this makes any sense—figuratively shoves it in your face while keeping it hidden. :-)  You *must* work with it.

The simplest explanation for what the index *is*, is that it's the place where you *build the next commit*.  It sits "between" the current commit and the work-tree.  It holds a copy of every file *from* the current commit, in the same special, Git-only, compressed format that Git uses inside commits.  Crucially, the index copy of the file is *writable*, unlike the frozen committed version.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can actually view the index directly, using `git ls-files --stage`.  This is impractical in many repositories, though, because this finds *every* file, which is not what we care about.

---

Thus, when you `git checkout master` or `git checkout xo-lib`, Git in effect starts by filling in the index with all the files from the latest `master` or `xo-lib` commit.  In other words, it gets the frozen copy of the file into the index.  As it goes, it also fills in the work-tree, expanding out the frozen copy into a usable form.  When this is done, your work-tree has all your files, ready to use.

**Once you make *changes* to you work-tree, your index and work-tree now differ.**  This is when you *stage* files, using `git add`.  All this does is *copy* the work-tree version into the index.  Git compresses the file into the special, Git-only format, and replaces whatever *was* in the index with the new copy.  If the file is all-new—if there was no index copy—this puts the file into the index.

If the work-tree version of a file differs from the index version of that file, Git says that this file is *not staged for commit*.  If the work-tree file matches the index version, but the index version does not match the `HEAD` version, Git says that this file is *staged for commit*.  It's possible for a file to be different in *all three* versions, in which case it's both staged *and* not-staged!  You won't get this with `git add`, though, since `add` means *copy work-tree version into index*, after which they will match.

#### How `git commit` works, including freezing the index

The secret to Git's speed is that the index has everything ready to go for the next commit.  The `git commit` command just has to collect your log message, then freeze all the index files and link them into the new commit.  Once it's done, the new commit and the index match, because the new commit is made *from* the index.

The new commit's parent commit is the then-current commit.  Assuming we are on commit `L` as shown above, we will make a new commit `M`:

```
...--L   <-- xo-wip (HEAD)
      \
       M
```

and then Git will update the current *branch name*, in this case `xo-wip` to which `HEAD` is attached, so that it points to our new commit `M`:

```
...--L--M   <-- xo-wip (HEAD)
```

Since `M` was made *from* the index, `M`'s frozen files match the index.  By definition, there is nothing to unstage because everything that Git was calling "staged"—everything where the index copy of some file differed from the copy frozen into `L`—is now frozen into the current commit `M`.  All the other files where `L` and `M` match are frozen into `M` too: they're just shared.  The index is all ready to go for more work and more commits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to the party for the original poster, but for others the simple answer is:

```bash
git reset --soft master
```

Say over the course of 15 commits, you've modified 40 files, after this command you'll be left with the 30 modified files all in the "staging area", but not committed.

Then if you want to transfer some of these changes to a new branch, just your normal process, i.e. something like this:

```bash
# stash all these changes
git stash

# create a new branch, starting from up-to-date master
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout -b my-new-branch

# pop your changes onto the new branch
git stash pop

# then commit only the changes you want
```